# How do i make my application restart every 5 minutes. I tried threads but it restarted only oncce

Tags: spring, spring-boot, refresh

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class CurdingApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(CurdingApplication.class, args);
    }
    
    @Bean
    CommandLineRunner runner(SnapshotsService SnapshotsService) {
        return args -> {
            ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
            mapper.enable(DeserializationFeature.ACCEPT_SINGLE_VALUE_AS_ARRAY);
            TypeReference<Snapshots> typeReference = new TypeReference<Snapshots>(){};
            InputStream inputStream = TypeReference.class.getResourceAsStream("/json/snapshots.json");
            try {
                Snapshots indexs = mapper.readValue(inputStream,typeReference);
                SnapshotsService.saveIndex(indexs);
                System.out.println("Users Saved!");
            } catch (IOException e){
                System.out.println("Unable to save users: " + e.getMessage());
            }
        };
    }
}
```

The application runs the command line runner when the application starts. I basically want the commandline runner to run every 5 mins

Comment: Try utilizing `spring-boot-batch` , you can configure cron expressions within and let your code run within a `job` in batch ! It will be triggered every `x` interval whichever you specify !

Comment: If this is a command line job why is it even still running? Did you include scheduling or web related things? If so don't else figure out what is keeping it alive. Then schedule a cron job to launch your app every x minutes. Or ditch the commandlinerunner and use an `@Scheduled` to trigger every 5 minutes. You don't need Spring Batch for that just regular Spring.

Comment: Alternatively, you can use `Timer` class in Java as well , https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/java-util-timer-class-java/